# List View Button to Launch Salesforce Flow?

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow, custom-button, visual-flows

I need to create a custom List view button that launches a Flow to update records. Is it possible to distribute a Flow via Custom List View button?

Comment: This is an old post but should still work in the new Builder UI: https://bigassforce.com/flow-list-buttons